# C# How to get thread info from external process? Like name of the module which created the thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, suspend, external-process

Basically what i'm trying to do is something like this:

[image: Start Adress]

Pseudo code:

```
if(ThreadMomModule.Name == "Skype.dll")
{
Thread[] aa = MomModule.Threads;

  foreach(Thread at in aa){
   Suspend(aa);}
}
```

Comment: If you can [get the thread id](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683233(v=vs.85).aspx), then you should be able to call [GetProcessIdOfThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683216(v=vs.85).aspx), and from there get all the info you need.